# Is there a way to record an action that sets guides to a 3 or 5 grid for a variable doc size?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, grids

I'm looking to record an action that will set guides in a 3x3, 5x5, 3x5 and 5x3 grid on my canvas in equal partitions, but I want it to be able to work for any document size.

I'm interested in doing this in InDesign, Illustrator and Photoshop. Is there a way to do this? A script I can install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using http://guideguide.me/ for grids and mockups in Photoshop for a while (sadly im unsure if you can get it for other programs yet) its a great tool and really speeds things up.

It may be possible to combine this plugin with an action, or equally it now has presets which you maybe able to set up. But also its pretty quick to just type in 5 twice and click go

Comment: This works really well for photoshop. Now if only I can get it to work for illy and indesign.

Answer (score 0):

I had a new thought use the above then use the method listed here - http://forums.adobe.com/message/3501035 to convert the guides to paths - then copy them into illustrator - my indesign knowledge is poor but i imagine you should be able to copy them into there too